# Different way for XSLT to loop through Nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, nodes

I've recently come upon a little smal challenge, while I do believe that a lot of people just stick with the -ForEach- loop as we usually do, I'm trying to think outside and see what alternative ways we have to actually to the same thing but in a different way.

There is another way to actually loop through the child nodes in this XSLT but I'm having a little hard time to actually figure it out. I've been searching through the forum without an answer but perhaps someone can point me in the correct direction.

My codes looks like this atm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Cars</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>regyear</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="autoads/ad">
      <xsl:if test="type = 2">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="model"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="regyear"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>    
          <td><xsl:value-of select="adtext"/></td>      
        </tr>
      </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="uppgift1.xsl"?>
<autoads>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Honda</name>
        <model>XL 1000 V</model>
        <regyear>2001</regyear>
        <price>129900</price>
        <adtext>2001 Honda XL 1000 V, 8.900 km. hög vindruta. Pris 129.900kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Nissan</name>
        <model>Almera 1.4S</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>119000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Nissan Almera 1.4S, 5 dörrar, met, 70.000 km. el.spegel/fönster, galv. kaross, c.lås, startspärr, airbag, nedfällb. baks. ABS, ute temp. R/CD, alarm, d.fäste, v.säten, s/v-hj.  EU-godk. full service, servo. Pris 119.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>5 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Mercedes-Benz</name>
        <model>C220 Elegance</model>
        <regyear>1995</regyear>
        <price>209000</price>
        <adtext>1995 Mercedes-Benz C220 Elegance, 4 dörrar, 88.000 km. skinn, klima/automatic, cruise, el.spegel/fönster, alu.fälgar, c.lås, airbag, antispinn,  ABS, ute temp, radio, s/v-hjul, servo, creme skinn. automat. Pris 209.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>S8</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>850000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Audi S8, 4 dörrar, 40.000 km. 4x4, Tiptronic-aut., klimataut., ABS, el.fönster/speglar/säten, soltak, c.lås, servo, airbag, startspärr, antispinn, cruise., alu., träinred., sort skinn, mitttarmstöd., sportssäten, stereo, alarm, s/v-hjul, dragkrok, 17"+18"alu. Pris 850.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Yamaha</name>
        <model>Thunderace 1000</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>130000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Yamaha Thunderace 1000, 11.500 km. Röd/Silver,tankväska medföljer. 146hk Pris kan diskuteras vid snabb affär. Pris 130.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>A4 1.6</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>260000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Audi A4 1.6, 4 dörrar, 78.000 km. el.fönster, ABS, alu. airbag, , klima, ESP, navig. plus, TV, evt. inbyte, power box (+30 HK) medföljer. Pris 260.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Jeep</name>
        <model>Grand Cherokee 2.5TD</model>
        <regyear>0</regyear>
        <price>359000</price>
        <adtext>0 Jeep Grand Cherokee 2.5TD, Stv., 38.000 km. A/C, el.fönster/spegel, 8xalu., c.lås, airbag, R/CD, s/v-hjul, servo. Pris 359.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>TL 1000 R</model>
        <regyear>1998</regyear>
        <price>110000</price>
        <adtext>1998 Suzuki TL 1000 R, 8400 km. Pris 110.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Volkswagen</name>
        <model>Golf 1.8 Pink Floyd</model>
        <regyear>1994</regyear>
        <price>85000</price>
        <adtext>1994 Volkswagen Golf 1.8 Pink Floyd, 4 dörrar, 135.600 km. Eu-godkänd, airbag, el.taklucka, just ratt, metallic, radio/CD/Kass, s/v-hjul, servicebok, servo, stereo. Fullständig service, 1 ägare, 6 högtalare. Pris 85.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Volvo</name>
        <model>850 2.0 LT</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>245490</price>
        <adtext>1997 Volvo 850 2.0 LT, Stv., 122785 km. halvskinn, el.spegel/fönster/soltak, fj.c.lås, st.spärr, airbag, just.ratt, rails, nedf.baksäte, m.armstöd, ABS, rad/kass, alarm, dragkrok, s/v-hjul, f.glass, met, garanti, servo. Pris 245.490 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>A3 1.6 Ambition</model>
        <regyear>1998</regyear>
        <price>180000</price>
        <adtext>1998 Audi A3 1.6 Ambition, 3 dörrar, 88.000 km. s/v-hj. el.fönster, ABS, f.glass, alu. c.lås, servo, airbag, rökfri, stilig bil. Pris 180.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>3 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>BMW</name>
        <model>K 1200 RS</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>195000</price>
        <adtext>2000 BMW K 1200 RS, 4.000 km. sidoväskor, bagagefästen. Pris 195.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1200</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>Baleno 1.6 GLX</model>
        <regyear>1999</regyear>
        <price>175000</price>
        <adtext>1999 Suzuki Baleno 1.6 GLX, Stv., 49.500 km. A/C, el.fönster/speil, c.lås, airbag, rails, ABS, stereo, , servo. Pris 175.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>LS 650 Savage</model>
        <regyear>1987</regyear>
        <price>29000</price>
        <adtext>1987 Suzuki LS 650 Savage, röd. Pris 29.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>650</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>GS 500 E</model>
        <regyear>1993</regyear>
        <price>31900</price>
        <adtext>1993 Suzuki GS 500 E. Pris 31.900,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>500</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>BMW</name>
        <model>520 i</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>387000</price>
        <adtext>2000 BMW 520 i, Stv., 52.600 km. Skinn, klima, m.f.ratt, el.spegel/fönster, alu.fälgar, c.lås, airbag x 6, antispinn, rails, träint, ABS, rad/cd, alarm, dragkrok, met, servo, Pris 387.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Triumph</name>
        <model>Daytona T 595</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>115000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Triumph Daytona T 595, 13.000 km. Är som ny, karbon anlägg, nya däck, extra tank. Pris 115.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>955</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Mitsubishi</name>
        <model>Pajero 2.5 TD</model>
        <regyear>1987</regyear>
        <price>59000</price>
        <adtext>1987 Mitsubishi Pajero 2.5 TD, Stv. 4x4, dragkrok, servo, mycket utr., ingen rost. Pris 59.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
</autoads>
```

What I'm trying to do is actually do the same thing as I do with `<xsl:for-each select="autoads/ad">`

Just not using the actually For-Each.

I've been trying to use the "match" function and template and then using "apply-templates" but I cant get it too work so that the values actually end up in boxes as the first example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Cars</h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ad" />
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>regyear</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ad">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
        <!-- <td><xsl:apply-templates select="autoads/ad/model"/></td> -->
          <!-- <td><xsl:apply-templates select="autoads/ad/regyear"/></td> -->
         <!-- <td><xsl:apply-templates select="autoads/ad/price"/></td>  -->
          <!-- <td><xsl:apply-templates select="autoads/ad/adtext"/></td>        -->
       </xsl:template>
 <!--    </table> -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Anyone have any good tips on how to think?

Comment: It's certainly a good idea to learn how to use xsl:apply-templates as an alternative to xsl:for-each, because template rules are an essential tool for XSLT programmers. But it's also important to learn why different constructs are sometimes more appropriate. The main benefit of using xsl:apply-templates is that it can help to make your code more resilient to variations in the structure of the input document. Is that one of your goals?

Comment: Correct @Michael, something it's hard to actually know when and what/why do use the different methods.

Comment: As someone who wants to acquire a deeper understanding of the language, you are very much part of the target audience for my XSLT 2.0 book, which devotes a lot of space to this kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a couple of tips :

-first, it is adviced to use xsl version 2 (released in 2007 :P )

-second, apply-template is more efficient than for-each and it is designed specially for the thing you want to achieve. So here is how i would use apply-template in your code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Cars</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>regyear</th>
                    <th>price</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/autoads/ad"/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/autoads/ad">
    <xsl:if test="type = 2">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="model"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="regyear"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="adtext"/></td>      
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: "*apply-template is more efficient than for-each*" No, it's not.

Comment: The solution which you provided works really well, but i'm a little confused regarding "apply-template is more efficient than for-each". I see that the above commentator also referenced this. 
The mostly I've actually seen is the for-each method, but if you could provide with a more dedicated answer perhaps you could change my ways.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using `xsl:for-each` - but if you prefer using `xsl:apply-templates`, you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/autoads">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Cars</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>regyear</th>
                    <th>price</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ad[type=2]"/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ad">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="model"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="regyear"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
        </td>    
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="adtext"/>
        </td>      
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```